# Writing input to a process opened with Popen

Tags: python, bash

I have a program called my_program that operates a system. the program runs on Linux, and I'm trying to automate it using Python.
my_program is constantly generating output and is suppose to receive input and respond to it.
When I'm running my_program in bash it does work like it should, I receive a constant output from  the program and when I press a certain sequence (for instance /3 to change the mode of the system), the program responds with an output.

to start the process I am using:

```
self.process = Popen(my_program,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,text=True)
```

And in order to write input to the system I am using:

```
self.process.stdin.write('/3')
```

But the writing does not seem to work, I also tried using:

```
self.process.communicate('/3)
```

But since my system constantly generating output, it deadlooks the process and the whole program gets stuck.

Any solution for writing to a process that is constantly generating output?

Edit:
I don't think I can provide a code that can reproduce the problem because I'm using a unique SW that my company has, but it goes somthing like this:

```
self.process = Popen(my_program,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,text=True)
self.process.stdin.write('/3')
# try to find a specific string that indicated that the input string was received
string_received = False
while(string_received = False):
    response = self.process.stdout.readline().strip()
    if (response == expected_string): 
       break
```

Comment: please post a [repro].

Comment: @pynexj I edited my question to contain  something more clear, tnx

Comment: "does not seem to work" -- that's an interpretation, but the observable facts are missing. Please create a [mcve] and show what you saw.

Comment: Writing just a couple of bytes will not do anything until you flush the buffer. You can set a minimal buffer or turn off buffering when creating the subprocess.

Comment: @tripleee Can u elaborate on to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The operating system implements buffered I/O between processes unless you specifically request otherwise.

In very brief, the output buffer will be flushed and written when it fills up, or (with default options) when you write a newline.

You can disable buffering when you create the `Popen` object:

```
self.process = Popen(my_program, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, text=True, bufsize=1)
```

... or you can explicitly `flush()` the file handle when you want to force writing.

```
self.process.stdin.flush()
```

However, as the documentation warns you, if you can't predict when the subprocess can read and when it can write, you can easily end up in deadlock.  A more maintainable solution might be to run the subprocess via `pexpect` or similar.

Comment: A few corrections: `flush()` deals with flushing *user mode* (not "operating system implemented") buffers. And `bufsize=1` is turning on line-buffering, not a 1 byte buffer, not disabling buffering entirely; since the OP isn't writing newlines, it won't fix the problem for short writes like `'/3'`. Even with `flush`, they'll likely still have problems on the `my_program` side (ignoring the "two-way lives comms lead to deadlock issue"), since it's likely to have buffers on `stdin` that may interfere with receiving the data immediately. In short, your last paragraph is the best advice here.

Comment: I also tried pexpect but my_program doesn't respond to sendline('/3).
my_program was written in C, it basically writes output to screen while waiting for user input from the keyboard which is picked up by getchar(). I tried printing what my_program receives as input, and the input from all the writing methods I tried (except when I run it in bash with keyboard input) is not recognized by my_program at all.

Comment: If the program is your own, probably make it listen to a network socket instead.

Comment: @Kuper `sendline()` will send an extra ENTER char. use `send()` since you only want to send `/3`.